# How to share a server connection between different powershell runspaces in c# on a web application

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm working on a web project and I need to do the following.
I want to run different cmdlets on a VMM server (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246490.aspx).

Right now when I need to run a cmdlet I open a runspace, connect to the VMM server using this cmdlet:
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj613273%28v=sc.20%29.aspx 
and then disconnect.

The problem is that disconnect doesn't work as expected and so I have memory leaks.

The solution is to use one connection to the server,using the previous cmdlet, and then perform all other actions via this connection (on new runspaces).

So I need to share the fact that I'm connected on each new runspace I open. I suppose I should use the RunspacePool class and maybe the InitialSessionState member but I'm not sure.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you say you "disconnect from the session", are you using Disconnect-PSSession or Remove-PSSession?

Comment: I mean i disconnect from the server vmmConnection=Get-SCVMMServer ......  and finally $vmmConnection.Disconnect();

Comment: Are you trying to do things in parallel here?  It can be dangerous to share objects across multiple runspaces; PowerShell offers you pretty much zero thread safety.

If you're not trying to do anything in parallel, it might be easier to just save the runspace rather than the connection object.  You can create new PowerShell objects using the same runspace, as needed.

Comment: Things need to run in parallel.If i share the connection why could this be a problem? Thanks for replying!

Comment: It just depends on whether that server connection object is threadsafe or not.  If it's not, then you will potentially run into big, hard to troubleshoot problems when sharing the object.  One compromise could be to create a runspace pool, set up a connection object in each runspace, and then keep the pool open.  That will allow some amount of parallel execution (up to the number of runspaces in the pool), without directly sharing objects.

Comment: I would like to test it.Do you have any ideas on how to share a variable(object) in c# ? Maybe through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.sessionstateproxy.setvariable%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I've done this using the InitialSessionState class.  There's some demonstration code of this (in PowerShell, but easily converted to C#) on my blog post here:  https://davewyatt.wordpress.com/2014/04/06/thread-synchronization-in-powershell/